# Merging on non-unique column - pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, join, merge

I have been trying to merge two `DataFrames` together (`df` and `df_details`) in a similar fashion to an Excel "vlookup" but am getting strange results. Below I show the structure of the two `DataFrames` without populating real data for simplicity

```
df_details:

Abstract_Title  |  Abstract_URL  |  Session_No_v2  | Session_URL | Session_ID
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
Abstract_Title1    Abstract_URL1         1          Session_URL1     12345
Abstract_Title2    Abstract_URL2         1          Session_URL1     12345
Abstract_Title3    Abstract_URL3         1          Session_URL1     12345
Abstract_Title4    Abstract_URL4         2          Session_URL2     22222 
Abstract_Title5    Abstract_URL5         2          Session_URL2     22222
Abstract_Title6    Abstract_URL6         3          Session_URL3     98765
Abstract_Title7    Abstract_URL7         3          Session_URL3     98765

df:

Session_Title   |   Session_URL   |   Sponsors   |    Type    |   Session_ID
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Session_Title1     Session_URL1        x, y z     Paper             12345
Session_Title2     Session_URL2         x, y      Presentation      22222
Session_Title3     Session_URL3        a, b ,c    Presentation      98765
Session_Title4     Session_URL4          c        Talk              12121
Session_Title5     Session_URL5         a, x      Paper             33333
```

I want to merge along `Session_ID` and I want the final `DataFrame` to look like:
[image]

I've tried the following script which yields a `DataFrame` that duplicates (several times) certain rows and does strange things. For example, `df_details` has 7,046 rows and `df` has 1,856 rows - when I run the following merge code, my `final_df` results in 21,148 rows:

```
final_df = pd.merge(df_details, df, how = 'outer', on = 'Session_ID')
```

Please help!

Comment: check your df with Session_ID wether they contain duplicate ?

Comment: They do contain duplicates - a single session ID is used for multiple abstracts.

Comment: For example df_details contain 3 12345 and df contain 2 12345, after merge you will see 6

Comment: Yes, I want it to be duplicated because the corresponding abstract information for some of them is different. Think of it as a hierarchy where sessions are the highest level and some sessions only have on abstract and some sessions have multiple. I have information about the session and information about the abstract and I want to merge them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate your final output table I used the following code:

```
final_df = pd.merge(df_details, df[['Session_ID',
                                'Session_Title',
                                'Sponsors',
                                'Type']], left_on = ['Session_ID'], right_on = ['Session_ID'], how = 'outer')
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, this still didn't work for me. It duplicates some of the output...

Comment: If you could provide what your output looks like, I could have a look at it later. Because after recreating your dataframes, the code above generated the exact output table you had mentioned. Also what is your concern with duplicates? Reason I ask is because the Session_ID column appears to be a many to one relationship (which could explain the larger increase in table size you had mentioned).

Comment: I think the easiest way to show the real output is to provide all the files I scraped from a website that I'm trying to merge. Not sure how to do that on Stack Overflow. I suppose i could also remove duplicates after merging by creating a column that concatenates two identifiers to create a unique one...

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a concatenated field. The Session_ID should be exactly equal in both tables. I.e. no need to create a column with "12345_12345" when 12345 individually in both tables will map correctly.

Comment: I do because Session_ID is not unique and also varies in number of occurrence for each ID. It is also not equal in both tables. There's a very easy manual solution if doing vlookup or index/match in Excel. Abstract_ID is unique but does not apply to all observations (some are left "blank" but still have a session ID). It worked after I concatenated the two columns to create a unique ID!

Answer (score 0):

Use 'left' instead of 'outer'.

```
final_df = pd.merge(df_details, df[['Session_ID','Session_Title','Sponsors','Type']], left_on = ['Session_ID'], right_on =['Session_ID'], how = 'left')
```